# A pointwise limit (depending on each point) of a sequence of bounded conitnuous functions is necessarily measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

Now, for each $x \in [0,1]$ we choose a convergent subsequence of $\{ f_n(x) \}$ (depending on $x$) and denotes its limit as $f(x)$.

Then, I wonder if the bounded function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is necessarily Borel-measurable.

This seems quite tricky to prove / disprove.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Try to work out which functions $f$ you can obtain in this way.

Comment: @legionwhale That is the very problem. I cannot figure out at all....

Comment: Hint: consider $f_n(x) \equiv q_n$ where $(q_n)$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$.